# Launch applications at login only for specific user, not shown in "Login Items"

Tags: launchd

To summarize, I want to make applications that launch at login launch only for specific user. They are not shown in 'Login Items' in System Preferences, but in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`.

My MacBook has applications for my work such as VPN, privacy files manager, and messenger for work, etc. To separate them (so that they cannot even startup at login) and project files, I tried to do by adding new my own user. However, when I boot up with the new user, it launches all applications I mentioned above as same as the work user. I found that it starts from `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, not by 'Login Items' in System Preferences.

I tried to move it to `~/Library/Launch*/` naively. They successfully launch at login only on my work user, but they didn't work correctly. For example, VPN starts up without its settings, and some applications remain as "Not Responding" state. I also tried to change their plist owner from root to user by `sudo chown {work-user} ~/Library/LaunchAgents/*` (also for `LaunchDaemons`) but didn't work.

I want plist in `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons` to work only on a specific user (or exclude a specific user). Can you advise?